# Is there a C/C++ implementation of Tensorflow conv2d?

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

Is there a C/C++ implementation of the Tensorflow conv2d. I am looking for some code easy to read and not necessary optimized.

There is a very brief description https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d, can you give me some more details on the underlying implementation?

Comment: You mean the kernel of the conv ops?
 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc

Comment: @greeness that may be a starting point, but I was searching for any additional documentation.